# mPDF PHP library strange error

Tags: php, mpdf

I have searched around the web looking for something about this, and I have not found anything:

```
Problem: Image object not found for background pattern
```

What I am doing is importing a pdf page from an external PDF, using the docs as my guide, but I keep getting this error when I output the finished pdf. This was working recently. My code is below:

```
$mpdf = new mPDF();
$mpdf->SetImportUse();

foreach ($orders->result() as $order) {
    $pdf = $shipments->getArtifact($order->artifact_url);
    file_put_contents(HOMEPATH . "invoice_pdfs/" . $order->id . "temp.pdf", $pdf);
    $pagecount = $mpdf->SetSourceFile("invoice_pdfs/" . $order->id . "temp.pdf");
    $tplId = $mpdf->ImportPage($pagecount, 50, 50, 100, 100);
    $mpdf->UseTemplate($tplId, '', '', 100, 100);
    $mpdf->WriteHTML('<pagebreak />');
    unlink("invoice_pdfs/" . $order->id . "temp.pdf");
}
$mpdf->Output("invoice_pdfs/myCave" . date('Ymd') . "Labels.pdf", 'F');
```

Comment: Try upgrading your mPdf to latest.

Comment: Trying that now. Its a bit of PITA due to how this was set up.

Comment: @SugatoSengupta Did not resolve anything. I updated first to 5.7 from 5.4 and no luck, and 6.1 exited without doing anything and with no errors.

Comment: What kind of server are you using?

Comment: @SugatoSengupta Ubuntu 14.04 server with php 5.5.9. Oddly it works when I call the files directly, but when I use the above code its a no go.

Comment: Looks like an unpatched issue of mPDF to me.. Also, do try using absolute path everywhere in your script.